# How do I allow user input to pick a variable to be used in a function in python with yfinance

Tags: python-3.x, yfinance

I have a function that prints currents price of a given contract
When I use the ticker (EURUSD=X) it displays price correctly

Although for convenience I would prefer to use a variable (EUR) for EURUSD=X
Whenever I attempt this, with my code, it prints *"IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0"*

**Here's the code: **(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS14u.png)